# I want to make an spinner when i select any item just fetch data from firestore database and put into the textviews

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, android-spinner

I want to make an spinner when i select any item just fetch data from fire store database and put into the text views

Comment: I am afraid your question is, by all means, extremely difficult to understand. Please provide some code that shows us what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please read the following tips about [How do I ask a good question on SO ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to  improve your chances of getting an answer. When you have all the details you can edit your question.